# 道を行ったところ meaning "just down the road"?

Tags: grammar, particle-の, relative-clauses

In the sentence

> うちの前の道を行ったところの家の男の子ったら、うっかりして指に《スーパーグルー》をくっつけてしまって、その指で鼻をさわったのよ

I would translate this as

> There is a boy *just down our street*, who carelessly got glue on his finger and then picked his nose.

I presume ったら is some sort of colloquial way of saying "there was". Though I'm not sure. Regardless, I am having serious trouble interpreting 道を行ったところの家

But my guess on 道を行ったところの家 feels shaky at best. How should one break this grammar down? Why do we need の? Is 道を行ったところ a relative clause? Can we also say things like

- 店を入ったところのポスター
  The poster just inside the shop
- 家を出たところの小包
  The parcel just outside the house

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The translation is fine.

Grammatically, it is just *Location Expression + の + A* meaning *A located in..*. They are the same as 新宿の店 (shop at Shinjuku) or そこの本 (book there).　This [dictionary entry](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%81%AE/#je-58755) lists 所在 explicitly as a meaning of の.

For the sentence, the location expression is うちの前の道を行ったところ, which literally means *the place where (you arrive when) you go down the street in front of us/our house*. So, *just down the street*.

店を入ったところのポスター is fine, but 家を出たところの小包 sounds strange to me. Probably it is because describing *at the door* as *going out of the house* is just strange (in English, you'd just say *there is a parcel at the door*, not really *if you go out of the house, you'll find a parcel*.). ドアのところの小包/家の外の小包 is fine. Also, 家を出たところ**にある**小包 is acceptable though still odd. (BTW what do you call 置き配 in English if I may ask?)

Comment: 置き配 is just "delivery".  There's really no special name for leaving a parcel at one's front door.  If you said "front door delivery" or "front porch delivery", you'd be understood.  More often than not, you would say "they left the package inside my front door" or "please leave the package on my front porch".  ("inside" my front door usually means between the storm door, which most homes have, and the real door.)